# ExtJS Tabpanel and JSON data not loading?

Tags: javascript, json, forms, extjs, tabpanel

I am using a tabpanel with two panels, where I am retrieving data through JSON. Retrieving data in the first tabpanel seems to work great, however, I can't parse the data retrieved from the JSON in the second tabpanel. Any ideas?

```
var registrationformPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
   frame:true,
   border:true,
   labelWidth: 125,
   url:'content/registercompany/registercompany.php?mode=createRegistercompany',
   sortInfo:{field: 'company_id', direction: "ASC"},
   reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
             root: 'results'
         }, [
    {name: 'company_id', sortType : 'int'},
    {name: 'company_name'},
    {name: 'orgno'},
    {name: 'firstname'},
    {name: 'lastname'},
    {name: 'address1'},
    {name: 'postalcode'},
    {name: 'postalarea'},
    {name: 'phone1'},
    {name: 'mobile'},
    {name: 'fax1'},
    {name: 'email'},
    {name: 'www'},
    {name: 'bankaccount'},
    {name: 'member_password'},
    {name: 'member_confirm_password'},
                                {name: 'butikknummer'},                                     {name: 'bransje'},
                                {name: 'kommentar'},
                                {name: 'apningstider_hverdag'},
                                {name: 'stengetider_hverdag'},
                                {name: 'apningstider_helg'},
                                {name: 'stengetider_helg'},
                                {name: 'butikk_navn'},
                                {name: 'butikk_addresse'},
                                {name: 'butikk_telefon'},
                                {name: 'butikk_poststed'},
                                {name: 'butikk_postnummer'}
   ]),
   items: [{
                               // {
                     xtype:'tabpanel',
            plain:true,
            activeTab: 0,
            height:405,
           // defaults:{bodyStyle:'padding:15px'},
           defaults:{bodyStyle:'padding:10px'},
            items:[{

                title:'Firmainformasjon',
                //layout:'form',
               //layout:'column',
               layout:'column',
                defaults: {width: 200},
                //defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: [{
                    columnWidth:.50,
                    layout: 'form',
     items: [
      company_id,
                                                 butikk_navn,
      company_name,
      orgno,
      firstname,
      lastname,
      address1,
      postalcode,
      postalarea,
                                                butikknummer,
                                                kommentar

                                               // apningstider_hverdag,
                                               // stengetid_hverdag
     ]
                                        },{
     columnWidth:.50,
     layout: 'form',
     items: [
      phone1,
      mobile,
      fax1,
      email,
      www,
      bankaccount,
      member_password,
      member_confirm_password

                                                //bransje
                                            ]
                }]
            },{

              title:'Butikkinformasjon',
                //layout:'form',
               //layout:'column',
               layout:'column',
                defaults: {width: 200},
                //defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: [{
                    columnWidth:.50,
                    layout: 'form',
     items: [
      //butikk_navn,
                                                butikk_addresse,
                                                butikk_poststed,
                                                apningstider_hverdag,
                                                stengetider_hverdag
     ]
                                        },{
     columnWidth:.50,
     layout: 'form',
     items: [
      butikk_telefon,
                                                butikk_postnummer,
                                                apningstider_helg,
                                                stengetider_helg,
                                                 bransje
                                            ]
                }]
            }]
```

And:

```
 if(id!="" && id!="[object Object]" && id!=undefined)
      {
       registrationformPanel.form.load({url:'content/registercompany/registercompany.php?mode=editRegistercompany&id='+id, 
                               waitMsg:'Loading'});

      }
```

Comment: Have you run this in Firebug or Chrome's debugger and checked whether there are any reported errors?  Also, this code snippet seems incomplete, I see that you have a JsonReader, but is there a Store for the FormPanel?  Where is grabbing the data from?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out the answer to my own question. The problem was solved by adding this:

```
 deferredRender: false,
```